# Showing unapproved comments in a discussion system

Tags: scala

In my project (which is a discussion system) there are approved and unapproved comments. There's a class that tells if unapproved comments should be shown. But I cannot think of a good name for this class. Right now it's named `ShowUnapproved` but doesn't that sound like a `Boolean`? (Rather than a configuration setting.)

**Is the name `ShowUnapproved` clear to you? Or can you think of a better name?**

Here is the class:

```
sealed abstract class ShowUnapproved {
  def shallShow(post: Post): Boolean // a "post" is e.g. a comment
}


object ShowUnapproved {

  case object None extends ShowUnapproved {
    override def shallShow(post: Post) =
      post.someVersionApproved
  }

  case object All extends ShowUnapproved {
    override def shallShow(post: Post) = true
  }

  case class WrittenByUser(userId: String) extends ShowUnapproved {
    override def shallShow(post: Post) =
      post.userId == userId
  }
}
```

Here're two examples of how to use it:

```
PageReneder.renderPage(page, ShowUnapproved.All)
PageReneder.renderPage(page, ShowUnapproved.WrittenByUser(userId))
```

And what would you call instances of this `ShowUnapproved` class?

I'm currently naming them `showUnapproved` which definitively sounds like a `Boolean` to me, and might be confusing:

```
val showUnapproved = ...  // sounds like a Boolean but it is not

val anyPendingApprovalText: NodeSeq =
  if (showUnapproved.shallShow(post)) makePendingApprovalText(post)
  else Nil
  // does `showUnapproved.shallShow` above sound good to you?
```

Comment: ``ShowUnapproved`` looks like some kind of action because it starts with a verb. You should rename it to something that sounds like a noun. Another thing is that it sounds like complete overkill to write a whole class to represent something that sounds like a simple boolean value, but I'm not sure if that is relevant in this context.

Comment: @MichaelZedeler It does sound like an action, perhaps even more than like a boolean, I didn't think about that. — It's not intended as a simple boolean value though, because of the 3rd form that takes an ID. So I don't think it's overkill with a case class. — If one would use a boolean, then that would have to be combined with passing 2 arguments: bool + user-ID. And the user-ID would mean nothing if the bool was true. I don't like params that sometimes mean nothing

Comment: @MichaelZedeler Okay now I've come up with a name, but it's rather long. `VisibilityOfUnapprovedThings`

Comment: Yep. Its long :) I guess we're still not quite there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
sealed abstract class CommentVisibility {
  def shallShow(comment: Comment): Boolean
}

object CommentVisibility {
  case object HideUnapproved
  case object ShowUnapproved
  case class ShowAllByUser(userId)
}
```

Usage:

```
renderPage(page, CommentVisibility.ShowUnapproved)
```

That's easy to understand :-) And can be amended to include e.g. showing/hiding comments with too many flags. (One would add another case class, perhaps using the [Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern))

And reminds of CSS I think: "visibility: hidden / visible"